# Have to search if a character is listed within a string using bisection and recursive function, Beginner here

Tags: python

I am doing course at edx and I have written a code but it is not giving the expected output. Have been trying to debut it for so much time but its still not working. Cant figure out what is the issue here. can you please guide

```
q=input('Enter the sentence \n')
y=input('Enter the character you want to search  \n')

def mids(x):

  if len(x)==0:
    return False 

  if len(x)==1:
    if x[0]==y:
      return True
    else:
      return False
  
  midindex=int(len(x)/2)

  if x[midindex]==y:
    return True

  elif y<x[midindex]:
    mids(x[:midindex])
  
  else:
    mids(x[midindex+1:])


print(mids(q))
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Binary search works on sorted data.

Comment: yup that is what I am entering in q as input. A alphabetically sorted string. but it still wont work corretly

Comment: You need to return the value of the recursive calls: `return mids(x[:midindex])`, etc.

Comment: Thank you!!!! ahh such a tiny problem and took soo much time. Thank you Johnny

Comment: Welcome to programming :)